# Does Ubuntu Core have RT-PREEMPT kernel?

Tags: kernel, raspberrypi

Does Ubuntu Core have RT-PREEMPT kernel for Raspberry Pi 3? If not, will there be support in the future?

Comment: Maybe this answer might help:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8970/default-kernel-preemption-vs-real-time-patch